# separate list elements based on semicolon

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list which is read from a file in the form of

```
 ['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32\n', '48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch\n', '49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32\n', '49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32\n', '49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128\n', '49052.tyrone-cluster;case3sqTS1e-4;mecvamsi;0;Q;qp32\n', '49053.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_1;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n', '49054.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_2;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n']
```

In this list i need to separate elements based on ;  and get the output of the list as

output should be:

```
 '48998','18:45:44','R','qp32'
 '48999','0','Q','batch'
 '49005','00:44:23','R','qp32'   (and so on till the end of the list)
 '49054','0','Q','batch'
```

which should be  written to file .Till now i tried codes like this but could not get the desired output.

```
parsed_data = [content[0].split(".")[0], content[3], content[4], content[5].strip()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of breaking out a function to do the parsing.  You can then use that function with map, or within a list comprehension.

```
inval = ['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32\n', '48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch\n', '49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32\n', '49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32\n', '49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128\n', '49052.tyrone-cluster;case3sqTS1e-4;mecvamsi;0;Q;qp32\n', '49053.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_1;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n', '49054.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_2;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n']

def parse(raw):
    parts = raw.strip().split(';')
    _id, _ = parts[0].split('.')
    return _id, parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]

print map(parse, inval)

# or 
# print [parse(val) for val in inval]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('48998', '18:45:44', 'R', 'qp32'),
 ('48999', '0', 'Q', 'batch'),
 ('49005', '00:44:23', 'R', 'qp32'),
 ('49032', '0', 'Q', 'qp32'),
 ('49047', '312:33:0', 'R', 'qp128'),
 ('49052', '0', 'Q', 'qp32'),
 ('49053', '0', 'Q', 'batch'),
 ('49054', '0', 'Q', 'batch')]
```

Personally I favor readability in this type of parsing.  Nested list comprehensions or more advanced techniques are completely acceptable, but simple, easy-to-follow code has extreme value in my book.

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32\n', '48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch\n', '49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32\n', '49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32\n', '49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128\n', '49052.tyrone-cluster;case3sqTS1e-4;mecvamsi;0;Q;qp32\n', '49053.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_1;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n', '49054.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_2;mcbkss;0;Q;batch\n']

answer = [operator.itemgetter(0,3,4,5)(s.split(';')) for s in L]
answer = [(t[0].split('.')[0], t[1], t[2], t[3].strip()) for t in answer]
```

Output:

```
Out[13]: 
[('48998', '18:45:44', 'R', 'qp32'),
 ('48999', '0', 'Q', 'batch'),
 ('49005', '00:44:23', 'R', 'qp32'),
 ('49032', '0', 'Q', 'qp32'),
 ('49047', '312:33:0', 'R', 'qp128'),
 ('49052', '0', 'Q', 'qp32'),
 ('49053', '0', 'Q', 'batch'),
 ('49054', '0', 'Q', 'batch')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lists = [item.split(';') for item in original_list]
list_of_tuples_final = [(li[0].split('.')[0], li[3], li[4], li[5].strip()) for li in list_of_lists]
```

The output is a list of tuples, along the lines of:

```
[('48998', '18:45:44', 'R', 'qp32'), ... , ('49054', '0', 'Q', 'batch')]
```